# Does Dead Man's Hand require you to have C4 equipped?

Tags: call-of-duty-modern-warfare-3

I haven't unlocked the Dead Man's Hand deathstreak yet, but it sounds rather cool. I was wondering though, does it require me to have C4 equipped in order to blow up in my opponent's face?

Answer (score 6):

No.

This perk functions similar to Last Stand, but you automatically pull out a detonator instead of a gun.

Comment: sounds like a mix between martyrdom and last stand. If you die does the C4 automatically detonate? What if no one shoots you, will you eventually stand back up?

Comment: The C4 automatically detonates whether anyone is nearby or not and there's no way to stand back up.